# Z3 with OCaml bindings: No implementations for Z and Q?

Tags: ocaml, z3

I'm trying to install Z3 with OCaml bindings.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, OCaml 4.05.0, OPAM 2.0.4, Z3 version 4.8.8 - 64 bit installed through OPAM (listed as z3 version 4.8.8-1).

I have exported the library path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.opam/system/lib/z3
```

I can load `#load "nums.cma";;` in the top-level.
However, when I attempt to load the z3 I get:

```
Error: Reference to undefined global `Q'
```

When I try to compile a program that uses Z3, I get:

```
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
Z referenced from ~/.opam/system/lib/z3/z3ml.cmxa(Z3)
Q referenced from ~/.opam/system/lib/z3/z3ml.cmxa(Z3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think those might be in the zarith package. If it indeed depends on that and it didn't get installed by opam, you should tell the maintainer of the opam package to update their package dependencies.

Comment: zarith is installed according to opam. Do I need to manually load it? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Not sure, but the instructions are here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/ml/README.md 
Perhaps you're trying to `#load` instead of `#require`?